# network to NAT in Virtual Box and strange IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I have just installed CENT-OS in a Virtual Box inside the internal network. The network setup is set to 'attached to NAT'. When I enable the network interface in CENTOS I can see that my IP address is 10.0.2.15. What iP address is that and is that safe to keep that setting?
With this I can use internet without any problem ..in case this setting should not the one to use which one should I use?

Comment: I am reading this http://whatismyipaddress.com/nat and looks like using NAT should be fine i.e. that ip is somekind a PRIVATE internal my company network. When I want to use internet is translated to something else. Can you advice whether I should be fine or I should be worry for something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 is a class A private IP range.  You shouldn't have any trouble using that IP.  But if you want to connect to services on that VM, you might want to use the bridged adapter setting instead. That way your VM will get its IP from the same DHCP server as any other device on your main network.  If you stick with NAT, you'll have to set up port forwarding for inbound connections from devices other than your host computer.

Comment: Hi trp4him!Thanks for the response. You are totally right. Yesterday I tried to use SSH to connect to that box and it didn't work . I switched to BRIDGED and all is works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following networks are for private (behind NAT/firewalls) use, and are not routed on the public Internet except through tunnels:

```
     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

This is from [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).